# Behavior of python's repr method

Tags: python

I understand that the goal of `repr` is to be unambiguous, but the behavior of `repr` really confused me.

```
repr('"1"')
Out[84]: '\'"1"\''
repr("'1'")
Out[85]: '"\'1\'"'
```

Based on the above code, I think `repr` just put `''` around the string.
But when i try this:

```
repr('1')
Out[82]: "'1'"
repr("1")
Out[83]: "'1'"
```

`repr` put `""` around strings and `repr("1")` and `repr('1')` is the same.

Why?

Comment: Try `print`ing the repr

Answer (score 1):

There are three levels of quotes going on here!

1. The quotes inside the string you're passing (only present in your first example).
2. The quotes in the string produced by `repr`. Keep in mind that `repr` tries to return a string representation that would work as Python code, so if you pass it a string, it will add quotes around the string.
3. The quotes added by your Python interpreter upon printing the output. These are probably what confuses you. Probably your interpreter is calling `repr` again, in order to give you an idea of the *type* of object being returned. Otherwise, the string `1` and the number `1` would look identical.

   To get rid of this extra level of quoting, so you can see the exact string produced by `repr`, use `print(repr(...))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The python REPL (and Ipython in your case) print out the `repr()` of the output value, so your input is getting `repr`ed twice.

To avoid this, print it out instead.

```
>>> repr('1') # what you're doing
"'1'"
>>> print(repr('1')) # if you print it out
'1'
>>> print(repr(repr('1'))) # what really happens in the first line
"'1'"
```

The original (outer) quotes may not be preserved since the object being `repr`ed has no idea what they originally were.

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr):

> repr(object): Return a string containing a printable representation of
>   an object.

So it returns a string that given to Python can be used to recreate that object.

Your first example:

> ```
> repr('"1"')    # string <"1"> passed as an argument
> Out[84]: '\'"1"\''    # to create your string you need to type like '"1"'.
> # Outer quotes are just interpretator formatting
> ```

Your second example:

> ```
> repr("'1'")    # you pass a string <'1'>
> Out[85]: '"\'1\'"'    # to recreate it you have to type "'1'" or '\'1\'',
> # depending on types of quotes you use (<'> and <"> are the same in python
> ```

Last,

> ```
> repr('1')    # you pass <1> as a string
> Out[82]: "'1'"    # to make that string in python you type '1', right?
> repr("1")    # you pass the same <1> as string
> Out[83]: "'1'"    # to recreate it you can type either '1' or "1", does not matter. Hence the output.
> ```

I both interpreter and `repr` set surrounding quotes to `'` or `"` depending on content to minimize escaping, so that's why output differs.