# Escape character inconsistencies in contractions in strings

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tokenize

I have text that I'm trying to process. Here are 2 examples:

```
Example 1: <p>An alternative way with <code>*</code>:</p>&#xA;&#xA;<pre><code>puts ["Toronto", "Maple Leafs"] * ', '&#xA;#Toronto, Maple Leafs&#xA;#=&gt; nil&#xA;</code></pre>&#xA;&#xA;<p>But I don't think anyone uses this notation, so as recommended in another answer use <code>join</code>.</p>&#xA;

Example 2: the thing is that I don't know what's the best way to solve it.
```

I am using BeautifulSoup and repr to process the text. They are being cleaned as:

```
Example 1:An alternative way with <code>*</code>:\n<code>puts ["Toronto", "Maple Leafs"] * \', \'\n#Toronto, Maple Leafs\n#=> nil\n</code>\nBut I don\'t think anyone uses this notation, so as recommended in another answer use <code>join</code>.\n

Example 2: the thing is that I don't know what's the best way to solve it.
```

My issue is with the escape character before the ' . Why is the don't in example 1 being processed at don'\t and the don't in example 2 being processed as don't without the escape character? How would I get them them to be processed the same way?

Here is my code for processing the text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html
def text_preprocessing(post):
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(post,'lxml')
    for e in soup.find_all():
       
    
        if e.name not in ['code']:
            e.unwrap()
            
    
    returnString=str(soup)  
    
    
    post = html.unescape(returnString)
    returnString=repr(post)
    returnString = returnString[1:-1]
    return (returnString)
```

Comment: You need to show your code

Comment: Not sure why this is but I played with this a little bit. What I found is this.The `repr` function seems to be the culprit.  Try this, `print(repr("\"'"))` returns `'"\''`. `print('\'')` returns `"'"`. Seems like as long as there are only single quotes or double quotes within the string, `repr` will use the other for the string to avoid escaping the quote character. If both are present, single quote is used no matter what and the single quotes are escaped.

Comment: Also this is why example 1 has escaped quotes. Put a double quote anywhere in example 2 and it will escape the single quotes.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45753722/behavior-of-pythons-repr-method) has an explanation on it.